# Change the name of folders on disk

Tags: powershell

I have a string in `"last name, first name"` format. The separator is the comma and I want to change the string so that it becomes `"first name, last name"`

In this example, I tried to do this with a directory list - but of course it doesn't work. Can someone see where it can be improved?

```
dir | rename-item -NewName { %{$data = $_.split(","); Write-Output "$($data[1]) $($data[0]))"}}
```

I have not posted the error that occurs as I would rather try to explain what I wish to accomplish . I want to change the naming structure of hundreds of directories on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would (eventhough pretty darn messy in my opinion) do the job.

*I suggest using the -WhatIf switch to try the actual renaming out first*

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName { % {$data = $_ -split(","); Write-Output "$($data[1]), $($data[0])".Remove(0,1)}}
```

Oh and by the way; "åstadkomma" is called accomplish in English. :)